# S3DB editor program

Tags: sql

i am trying to open a s3db database. 
can someone please recommend a program?

i have tried sqlite2009pro, and it does not recognize it.
Sqlite Admin says Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset.
sqlitestudio says s3db is not supported database-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either:

1. Download Sqlite Administrator from http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/

   - Freeware
   - Portable
   - Bug in export "text format" (=wide string) data
   - Bug in view, edit and export non English data
2. Download Sqlite Studio from http://sqlitestudio.pl/ **(RECOMMENDED)**

   - Freeware
   - Portable
   - unable to export big dbases

Answer (score 0):

In [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/), you can open S3DB as SQLite.